# How to use ternary expression in setState ()?

Tags: reactjs

I have a fetch functional like this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/kw-finder', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
      body: JSON.stringify({'firstParam': this.state.value,
                            'secondParam' : this.state.audienceMax})
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
        this.setState({queryResults: JSON.parse(json['query_results']),
                       dailyPreloadMetrics: JSON.parse(json['keyword_data']),
                       isLoading: false,
                       isHidden: false
                       })
      })

  }
```

This works; however, I want to conditionally set the value of `isHidden` state depending on the json results. So for example, I want to do something like this:

```
this.setState({queryResults: JSON.parse(json['query_results']),
                       dailyPreloadMetrics: JSON.parse(json['keyword_data']),
                       isLoading: false,
                       isHidden: (JSON.parse(json['keyword_data']) === '12') ? false : true
                       })
```

So basically if the JSON.parse(json['keyword_data']) === '12', then I want to change the value of the state. Is this possible?

Comment: the output of `(JSON.parse(json['keyword_data']) === '12')` isn't a boolean value?

Comment: yes, it is. however there is no need to use ternary in this case since you can check against 12 e.g `isHidden: JSON.parse(json['keyword_data']) !== '12'`

Comment: @RachelNicolas thank you!